# Comparing two tables without foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are two tables in 2 different databases one table consists of Salutations example `Mr`, `Miss` and other table has names with Salutation example `Mr.XYZ`, `Miss.ABC` so I need a query which will compare the two tables and gives only those names from table 1 which are of matching salutations.

Example :

```
Table 1                       Table 2

Salutation column             Name column
Mr.,                          Mr.Abc
Miss.,                        Mr.XYZ
Mr. & Mrs.                    Mr. & Mrs. Def
                              Jr. xyz
```

So the query needs to compare two tables and give the output as

```
Mr.Abc,
Mr.Xyz
Mr. & Mrs. Def
```

Comment: Have a look at `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `join` query with `like`:

```
select t2.*, t1.salutation
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.name like concat(t1.saluation, '%');
```

The one caveat is that this can return more than one match.  For instance, anything that matches "Mr. & Mrs." would also match "Mr.".  To fix this, you can choose the *longest* match, using `apply`:

```
select t2.*, t1.salutation
from table2 t2 cross apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t2.name like concat(t1.saluation, '%')
      order by len(t1.saluation) desc
     ) t1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your Quick Response Godron but i  have a Scenario
where 
Siranosh Sir
Siri Sir  Sir is a Salutation but Siranosh is not an Actual Saluation

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT T2.*, T1.Salutation
FROM MyDatabase2.Myschema2.Table2 as T2 
INNER JOIN MyDatabase1.Myschema1.Table1 as T1
    ON T2.Name LIKE '%'+T1.Salutation+'%'
```

Comment: Thanks DaleK  but i have a Scenario with name as Siranosh and its comparing with Salutation SIR and giving as a Match

Comment: use an space after t1.Salutation:  `SELECT T2.*, T1.Salutation`
`FROM MyDatabase2.Myschema2.Table2 as T2 `
`INNER JOIN MyDatabase1.Myschema1.Table1 as T1`
    `ON T2.Name LIKE '%'+T1.Salutation+' '+'%'`

Comment: @Rohith not my answer - I just edited it. And you need to ensure your question contains a complete representation of the problem.

Comment: @DaleK SELECT T2.*, T1.Salutation FROM MyDatabase2.Myschema2.Table2 as T2  INNER JOIN MyDatabase1.Myschema1.Table1 as T1 ON T2.Name LIKE '%'+T1.Salutation+' '+'%' this worked

Comment: nice! I am glad I helped you.

Comment: @tty0 This worked but performance is bad Table A has 117783722 and Table B has 300 Distinct Tittles so when comparing its taking for ever.

Comment: @Rohith Gordon's solution will perform better. As soon as you add "%" at the start of your match you must do an entire table scan. Using it last means indexes can be used.